# JMH microbenchmarking on java api which uses parallel execution via Completable Future

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future, jmh

I need to measure performance of my build method using JMH tool. The build method basically creates multiple threads internally by Completable Future in order to achieve parallel execution for loading an in memory object called dictionary.

However when I am performing benchmarking on the below method:

```
@Benchmark
 public Dictionary buildDictionary() {
   DictionaryCreator dictionaryCreator =
       new LocalFSDictionaryCreator("metadata_avro_files");
   return dictionaryCreator.build();
 }
```

@Benchmarking method is called multiple times on every iterations/Warmup causing
"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError : unable to create new native Thread"

What is the best way to achieve JMH on the code which is paralelly processing tasks?

Comment: Have you managed to resolve the issue? I think the problem was that you have to clean up leftovers after each iteration. It might be either a destroy method which ensures that all threads are finished or better if you use an Executor which you can shutdown

Comment: Yes I was able to solve this by shutting down the executor after each JMH iteration.